# why Type '[]' does not satisfy the constraint Parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to declare this function type:

```
function currying1 (fn: any, params: any) {
  if(fn.length <= params.length){
    return fn(...params)
  }
  return (...p: any) => currying1(fn, [...params, ...p])
}
```

Then I try to declare:

```
type Parameters2<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? Partial<P> : never

declare function Currying2<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any, P extends Parameters2<Fn> = []>(fn: Fn, params: Parameters2<Fn>): any
```

I want to set P default value to [], but i get this type error

> Type '[]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Parameters2'. (2344)

[Playground with code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBCMDsEFoIGECuAndBPAlgOwHMZJEEzySAjLCAQTwBcALAezxoDFUIAKAAQCGjAGaoAlBADETAegAmU2egFYSJSRogBFVAFMAzgxxs1UAHwQAKlgAOugMoBjdDhsMIAFgB0ABgg59CHRdRxYAWzDdPDldBXwIZgCIRxkAG1Sogl1TCABtNExcQgBdHiYGBht9AC5gYCivAHccAGtXWJwBLxZ0AmBmtuAC7HwCCSTmXQSQpjwcAEc9CBZhZLYAN110I0IIAQhRPEcjNgSZdwYBFoMIMNRUoxsMvd7USMZA-AYWPYh9XUWUUcUxWB1QRxOeECzAE7l0AhSCSuU32%20lGz1kBDeUQYXggOQ4PQgugAHgIwk9dNUcgADOkMfQkUJQ9wCOQKAC8vAE1QgeDelC2ABoIJRefywoL0BIORZ9gBqUVMtiGM7BKZctlyHjQEUAJjEOWZqscGBcsVo7IgXOGRQIPC1hqgxvcwhwm2tyTNOAt7J4Bp4AGYnRA6TScpYmFNDsdjHgIDYBPp-gpvqHbaMabcVBAZB67g9XBjXu8GSKsCxuHhdLEEj9QpgQgxUjQGLYpjhcTkAJLxxKBFICdKZXQiyZezA%20hQxyHLPAtvaOYFuOcoks4vashI4SJ4gDyRxR6TOa6xpf8gSTaII1bkIs7f1Y9wUwQYGHjncCwX09y7UBIFgAGo%20o0c4QAA4p2AASqBirmFRVLUwAMikXgAFb6N0vTAHAYAgMAYCEaAEAAPpkeRFHkRAACalboCgLAxBAUFbFMlHsWRED4YRbZ2BBugMFwEJxgAPLQIoAEoWFytDEiSDBRHIgS5PgwhbBAHDFBAAD8vA2LyHAyhYEkQLysmkgp0TKap6kcCKXgOTZ9ESQYDBabpPD6YZ1oWOBAlCbGbAiS5hiSRY4q6Js6CETEjipLI0bgoF8YZoQImWGYPDCHgvKWGIuVyZZSm8A5XiYjU-h4Gp9G0EZlXVRAEkkLpfmCUlkJiWFJARVFhEznGE4jIQ0C8NlvJCFgIqJsoYQVRNEgAN4kDgwhZXgXgZIQzAQCJXLTeSmGbQQzBiEtUBQK%2074HHgPClfts0hgAviQl3oPGt0OfpezsHVpqFKM0BrSKuR3bIB32Z9xSGs9YC8VMHCeg64oCsKoq8oYLiEHVE08e2GkAAqevjYORAp6D6HqIkcGYuN8Rw%20MjVyuQCNpyOSupAA%20EDgjEbq3iKlCs38DCY0QXM87ofOxMUtMdvolievTI0WYpgT0zpMCmRAer4nUxBwxeliM3kWkq1ZBMayNvI62AevQLDeMBJYOtMyzbNShA4vRJL%20DS4VqsW7pVva7rwD6478t6sbzNCxKUqm-JAfq0HWs23bDt8U7HiejH7uc9z3tS3eopCxjoyewXvO%208XjilyL5de1Xt4J0VauEyn1uh9rssQMTM0CVsFPpdJVj%20%20bH1lb0FVOb32PsBrfdGEOIn4%20FfKRVsMUhPFwRgsJpypQQlMcPGZvFRP5XjewuRQz532Tb3Y-FX35ID%20Tx94CPN%20ZWNGl4FNJMKov1JoPD%20Zh8r3z6u1AaWokZ8hRugAW6N65YzOkEASV0FRKhhi6a6xtD56gdOyYGeoRQAHJoBkKhoRW2IBSIcUolYVyKAkw3AYYw7iO4bA9AuHjBaEAACiiwhwigESSOwxwICPQOOgcIEAyF8DhggQcw5CAGGAKgIwqR9BkMIrgv65o5D4LNHaHgcCy6ECQfA9miDki8koCwFgGQhB1RFnoQ0%20jvSxBdigExowzE8mFqLKxcdUaOHsY45x-8IByAiU4%20E0SqSikiQkkUwhkHBIgAQOJUTXHoHcT3RwrDAhMxIGIiRDARJCNQMvEgUA4aggMVOXU3IMmjDqjwOCoTpR3x4OE5J8SXF3zcdkcwZghRlPEU2KpwjUgiTqQkdsjSvFyFIa0oJ7TeldIQR0-pDjBl4A6bEgZuTelJP2ac2Uo02lY16dkk5CS8l6AAuMsAMsaHEXYRRDSGBJj0XsApKo9CvkkS4gRUAAEID2BkLvCsGA-hOM0XGCq5RKg1DqChJg6FMI9D6HAYAQh9CNE3uYCAwFdCgX0IiyEKKELouQvoVCGEsJ4tgMAKlqQkUqkhQAWR6FMZAaQjoGF5KixCGLGVYuZbivCBEwBAA) (Error is on line 64)

Comment: Why are you using `params: any`?

Comment: currying1 just a javascript function, it show how this currying function work, it will be set [] when params is undefined